# Can't boot into recovery mode after flashing TWRP on Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-5, lineageos, heimdall

## Problem

I can not boot my Samsung Galaxy S5 into recovery mode after flashing TWRP.

## Background

I am trying to install [LineageOS](https://download.lineageos.org/klte) on my [Samsung Galaxy S5](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/klte).

## What I tried

I followed the install [guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/klte/install) on the LineageOS wiki:
1. Installing [heimdall](https://gitlab.com/BenjaminDobell/Heimdall/tree/master), which I built from source to get v1.4.2, since the previous version could not complete the handshake with my phone (other people had the same [error](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/209#issuecomment-353863005))
2. Checking if heimdall works by using `heimdall print-pit`, which it did
3. Flashing [TWRP](https://dl.twrp.me/klte/) by using `heimdall flash --RECOVERY twrp-x.x.x-x-klte.img --no-reboot`. Keeping their disclaimer in mind I tried both the current version as well as two older ones. Heimdall outputs `RECOVERY upload successful`, and I disconnect the phone (after the device has been released).
4. Booting into recovery mode -> **FAIL**

## Error

The device boots into download mode instead (and no, I did not accidentally switch the volume buttons). There is no error message.

## Edit

I originally (and wrongfully) assumed the device to be [Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/klte). It was, however, a [Samsung Galaxy S5 Plus](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/kccat6) (at least this is how I explain the error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Preface

I have found the solution to my particular problem now, but if someone else knows more about this feel free to improve my answer or post your own.

## Solution

Annoyed with what I thought to be heimdall's fault, I turned to [odin](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/7swanx/install_lineageos_onto_galaxy_s5_sm900w8/) (not in a religious way).

This, however, gave me the same error. Close to desperation, I decided to check everything that I did again, and luckily so: Because the guide was emphasizing that the TWRP version has to be the correct one for the model, with not even a little deviation, I checked and found that what I thought to be be a [Galaxy S5](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/klte) was actually named [Galaxy S5 LTE-A](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/lentislte). However, the model read "SM-G901F", which belongs to the [Galaxy S5 Plus](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/kccat6). So after downloading the correct [TWRP](https://dl.twrp.me/kccat6/) and [LOS](https://download.lineageos.org/kccat6) versions, everything went fine.

I am not sure if this was the only problem or if there is still a problem with heimdall, since the linked reddit thread suggests so.

## Conclusion

All this may be very well due to me not being patient enough to get the correct model before I start. In this case, I still hope that my error can serve someone else in their search, seeing as I linked a lot of resources (and maybe other people make the same mistake as me).